# Accelerating antielectrons

Tags: acceleration, antimatter

I just signed up to the site. I am not a physicist, but I find physics fascinating. My understanding and knowledge is very little.
I was doing some reading on Alpha collaboration 
< http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~fajans/ALPHA_Spanish/EN_utilidades.htm >
and they were answering a question about why the research on antimatter is so important. What interested me was one of the answers "(...)wants to study if matter and antimatter are exactly symmetrical." 
That made me wonder, if accelerating electron creates antielectron and gamma rays, then what would be created by accelerating an antielectron?

Thank you!

Effcia855

Comment: gamma rays (among many other possible outcomes ) are produced when an electron and antielectron collide and annihilate, but not when they are accelerated

Comment: Thank you for your replay! This is where I found my information. http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~fajans/ALPHA_Spanish/EN_produccion%20new.htm
As I said I am probably not understanding. Could it be created in both processes then?

Comment: Can you cite the part you don't understand? I'm not sure what is it :)

Comment: Sure!
It's the picture actually that presents how the acceleration works and how the electron breaks up. It is super simplistic :)
"Impact of electrons (e-)on the metal and production of antiparticles (e+) and gamma rays (g)"

Comment: I think [this](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1172) might answer your question

Comment: "anti-electrons" are typically called [*positrons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron).

Comment: And you may be interested in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4546) (arXiv link) about the electron & positron component of cosmic rays (which can generate gamma rays via bremsstrahlung and inverse Compton processes during acceleration).